# What options are available for a wireless remote for a Canon 50D?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, remote, canon-50d

I'm looking for a wireless remote for my Canon 50D, but the canon RC-5 and RC-6 don't seem to support it in the information I've found thus far.

Can anyone recommend anything that might work with bulb exposures and won't break the bank into a million bits like the LC-5?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your budget is, but I use the Hähnel Giga-T Pro with my 5D2, which allows for bulb exposures. It also acts as an interval timer for time lapse work, and as a standard wireless remote.

[£80 from Warehouse Express](http://www.warehouseexpress.com/buy-hahnel-giga-t-pro-remote-control-canon/p1519110)

Answer (score 2):

Also my vote for Hähnel Giga-T Pro. Really awesome device and can do lots of different things.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Canon products, there only seems to be the LC-5, according to [the 50D manual (Pg203)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/80.pdf). It does seem a bit overkill, and rather pricey, though. Another option may be to do something with PocketWizards, but since I don't use them myself I can't say how you'd set this up, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Whoa! That LC-5 is 729 smackers in AU. That's about 10 times more than I was hoping to spend. Does it at least make me breakfast? ;)